# 2 buttons with same CSS and JS are not working.

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/6/). This is my watch trailer button, the first button is working perfectly fine. But the second watch trailer button is not working.

What is the problem with it?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
<br>
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>

<div id="close">
<div id="trailerdivbox">
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <iframe id="video" class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" data-
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

#watchbutton {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
color: red;
font-weight: 600;
border: none;
/* This one removes the border of button */
padding: 10px 12px;
}

#watchbutton:hover {
background-color: #e2e2e2;
cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top:0%;
overflow: auto; /* Enable Scrolling */
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
/* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
/* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
max-width: 560px;
max-height: 315px;
width: 95%;
height: 95%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");

function playVideo() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var src = video.dataset.src;

video.src = src + '?autoplay=1';
}

function resetVideo() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

video.src = '';
video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
playVideo();
}

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
resetVideo();
} 
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the only problem, but both of your buttons have the same ID. This immediately is **a** problem that you need to fix. ID's are meant to be completely unique in relation to everything else in your document, meaning it that **no element should ever share an ID with another element**.

Comment: After you fix the issue with the double ids - mentioned by Frits, prasad & others - you still need to tell `playVideo` to play a different video, depending on which button you push. See [**my answer below**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330728/2-buttons-with-same-css-and-js-are-not-working/44331691#44331691) for a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `classname` instead of `id` .Because id is unique for whole html .For selector use with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8vLneqZ_UAhUGr48KHZMRCxQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw&sig2=T9CQUN4FIwOLswLOzlwXEQ)

**Updated**

declare src of the video in the `data-src` of  button .Then pass the argument  with `playvideo(this.dataset.src)` function .

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.watchbutton')

function playVideo(src) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+src + '?autoplay=1'; //add with iframe
}

function resetVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

  video.src = '';
  video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.forEach(function(a){
a.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  playVideo(this.dataset.src); // pass the src
}
})

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetVideo();
  }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

#watchbutton {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  /* This one removes the border of button */
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

#watchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable Scrolling */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="watchbutton" class="watchbutton" data-src="TDwJDRbSYbw">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
<br>
<button id="watchbutton" class="watchbutton" data-src="TDwJDRbSYbr">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>



<div id="close">
  <div id="trailerdivbox">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe id="video" class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Worked. But i forgot one more thing. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/8/

Both buttons are playing same video, can you please tell me, how to fix it? That box have soo many ID's, which one to fix?

Comment: @PunitMishra see my updated answer. i was edited as you required one

Answer (score 3):

you can not have same ids. change id to something else.

```
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
<br>
<button id="watchbutton2">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
```

Comment: The ID is linked to CSS + JS, i cannot change ID for each button in CSS + JS. It will make my page super slow. My page will have at least 20 buttons like that

Comment: you should use class then not id.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

After you fix the issue with the double ids - mentioned by Frits, prasad & others - you still need to tell `playVideo` to play a different video, depending on which button you push.

Here's how you can fix your code to achieve the desired result :

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("TDwJDRbSYbw");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("6H_0aem12_I");

function playVideo(id) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.dataset.src + id;

  video.src = src + '?autoplay=1';
}

function resetVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

  video.src = '';
  video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function(e) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  playVideo(this.id);
}

btn2.onclick = btn1.onclick;

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetVideo();
  }
}
```

```css
/* Watch Trailer Button CSS */

.btn {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  /* This one removes the border of button */
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#trailerdivbox {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable Scrolling */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="TDwJDRbSYbw">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
<br>
<button class="btn" id="6H_0aem12_I">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>

<div id="close">
  <div id="trailerdivbox">
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <iframe id="video" class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

---

[**See also this JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0xxe22/9/)

Comment: Is their any solution without making multiple variable in JS? Because, My page will have like 20 watch trailer buttons,  And I will make those 20 buttons using a PHP script, so I also need to make 20 Javascript, it will make the page dead slow

Comment: Like Prasad's solution

Comment: Just add `<button class="btn" id="VIDEOID">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>` + `var btnX = document.getElementById("VIDEOID");`  + `btnX.onclick = btn1.onclick;` for every button, where `VIDEOID` is the ID of your video and `X` is the number of your button. Everything else can be reused by the different buttons. I can assure you it doesn't get any more efficient than that...

Answer (score 0):

First, It is not good practice to use identical ids.

```
<button id="watchbutton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
```

And when you use

```
var btn = document.getElementById("watchbutton");
```

You get only one button (the first), You should use something like:

```
<button id="watchbutton" class="watchButton">Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
<br>
<button id="watchbutton2" class="watchButton" >Watch Trailer &#9658</button>
```

And get them with:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("watchButton");
```